# LEFT JOIN para contar registros de otra tabla en cada fila

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

¡Hola amig@s!

Tengo el siguiente problema:
Estoy tratando de obtener los registros de una tabla y en la misma consulta contar el número de registros de otra tabla que coincidan con el mismo ID mediante llave una foránea. Dejo la consulta que tengo, actualmente únicamente me muestra un registro y me cuenta todos los registros de la Tabla 2 sin tomar en cuenta el ID.

Tabla 1: id_attribute_group | name

Tabla 2: id_attribute | id_attribute_group | name

```
SELECT
g.*, COUNT(a.id_attribute_group) AS total_attributes
FROM attributes_groups g
LEFT JOIN attributes a
ON (a.id_feature_group = g.id_feature_group)
ORDER BY g.name
```

Gracias

¡Saludos!

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de las tablas en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Indica exactamente el resultado quieres obtener para esos datos de ejemplo. Aquí se explica mucho mejor [ask]. Bienvendo a [so]

Comment: La columna `name` ¿tiene valores únicos en ambas tablas? si no ¿qué resultado esperarías si se repiten valores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para contar los atributos por grupo:

```
SELECT g.*, count(a.id_attribute) total_attributes
  FROM attributes_groups g
    LEFT JOIN attributes a
       ON a.id_attribute_group = g.id_attribute_group
  GROUP BY g.id_attribute_group
  ORDER BY g.name
```

La tabla pivote es `attributes_groups` (donde no se repiten registros),
por lo tanto el `GROUP BY` lo haces sobre la llave primaria del pivote, considerando que existe un índice sobre esa columna y ayuda al desempeño;
Entonces la columna con *agregación* es `id_attribute` la cual al ser llave primaria contará cuántos atributos hay.

Answer (score 0):

Por el aspecto de tu intento, parece que buscas algo así:

```
SELECT * FROM attributes_groups LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id_attribute_group,
      COUNT(*) total_attributes
      FROM attributes GROUP BY 1  
  ) c1 USING(id_attribute_group);
```

Adjunto el dataset de test para que puedas hacer las comprobaciones:

```
CREATE TABLE attributes_groups(
  id_attribute_group int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre_grupo varchar(15)
  );
CREATE TABLE attributes(
  id_attribute int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  id_attribute_group int,
  nombre varchar(15),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_attribute_group) REFERENCES attributes_groups(id_attribute_group)
  );
INSERT INTO attributes_groups (nombre_grupo) VALUES
  ('grupo1'),('grupo2');
INSERT INTO attributes (id_attribute_group, nombre) VALUES
  (1,'atributo1'),(1,'atributo2'),(1,'atributo3'),
  (2,'atributo4'),(2,'atributo5');
```

Del que obtendrás este resultado:

> ```
> ================================================================
> | id_attribute_group |    nombre_grupo    |  total_attributes  |
> ================================================================
> |         1          |       grupo1       |         3          |
> ----------------------------------------------------------------
> |         2          |       grupo2       |         2          |
> ----------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

Por favor, déjame tus dudas en los comentarios para explicar la consulta conforme a tus necesidades.

Modifico tu consulta para que veas que sólo te faltó un `GROUP BY` y los campos por los que conectar las tablas:

```
SELECT
g.*, COUNT(a.id_attribute_group) AS total_attributes
FROM attributes_groups g
LEFT JOIN attributes a
ON (a.id_attribute_group = g.id_attribute_group)
GROUP BY nombre_grupo
ORDER BY nombre_grupo;
```